# Circular permutation in scheme

Tags: algorithm, recursion, scheme, racket, circular-permutations

Hello I try to make circular permutations in Scheme (Dr. Racket) using recursion.

For example, if we have (1 2 3) a circular permutation gives ((1 2 3) (2 3 1) (3 1 2)).

I wrote a piece of code but I have a problem to make the shift.

My code:

```
(define cpermit
  (lambda (lst)
    (cpermitAux lst (length lst))))

(define cpermitAux
  (lambda (lst n)
    (if (zero? n) '()
        (append (cpermitAux lst (- n 1)) (cons lst '())))))
```

Where (cpermit '(1 2 3)) gives '((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))

Comment: The issue here is that you never actually do anything to `lst` that would rearrange its elements. The only place it is actually used (as opposed to just threading it through calls to `cpermitAux`) is in `(cons lst '())`, which just uses `lst` without modification. The recursive call also just passes `lst` without modification, so all you’ve done is implement a `replicate` function.

Comment: Thx ! I added a rotate function and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function that shifts your list

```
(defun lshift (l) (append (cdr l) (list (car l))))
```

This will shift your list left.

Use this function before appendings

```
(define cpermit
  (lambda (lst)
    (cpermitAux lst (length lst))))

(define cpermitAux
  (lambda (lst n)
    (if (zero? n) '()
      (append (cpermitAux (lshift lst) (- n 1)) (lshift (cons lst '()))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a series of translations of @rnso's code, modified to use a recursive helper function instead of repeated `set!`.

```
#lang racket
(define (cpermit sl)
  ;; n starts at (length sl) and goes towards zero
  ;; sl starts at sl
  ;; outl starts at '()
  (define (loop n sl outl)
    (cond [(zero? n) outl]
          [else
           (loop (sub1 n) ; the new n
                 (append (rest sl) (list (first sl))) ; the new sl
                 (cons sl outl))])) ; the new outl
  (loop (length sl) sl '()))

> (cpermit (list 1 2 3 4))
(list (list 4 1 2 3) (list 3 4 1 2) (list 2 3 4 1) (list 1 2 3 4))
```

For a shorthand for this kind of recursive helper, you can use a named `let`. This brings the initial values up to the top to make it easier to understand.

```
#lang racket
(define (cpermit sl)
  (let loop ([n (length sl)] ; goes towards zero
             [sl sl]
             [outl '()])
    (cond [(zero? n) outl]
          [else
           (loop (sub1 n) ; the new n
                 (append (rest sl) (list (first sl))) ; the new sl
                 (cons sl outl))]))) ; the new outl

> (cpermit (list 1 2 3 4))
(list (list 4 1 2 3) (list 3 4 1 2) (list 2 3 4 1) (list 1 2 3 4))
```

To @rnso, you can think of the `n`, `sl`, and `outl` as fulfilling the same purpose as "mutable variables," but this is really the same code as I wrote before when I defined `loop` as a recursive helper function.

The patterns above are very common for accumulators in Scheme/Racket code. The `(cond [(zero? n) ....] [else (loop (sub1 n) ....)])` is a little annoying to write out every time you want a loop like this. So instead you can use `for/fold` with two accumulators.

```
#lang racket
(define (cpermit sl)
  (define-values [_ outl]
    (for/fold ([sl sl] [outl '()])
              ([i (length sl)])
      (values (append (rest sl) (list (first sl))) ; the new sl
              (cons sl outl)))) ; the new outl
  outl)

> (cpermit (list 1 2 3 4))
(list (list 4 1 2 3) (list 3 4 1 2) (list 2 3 4 1) (list 1 2 3 4))
```

You might have noticed that the outer list has the `(list 1 2 3 4)` last, the `(list 2 3 4 1)` second-to-last, etc. This is because we built the list back-to-front by pre-pending to it with `cons`. To fix this, we can just reverse it at the end.

```
#lang racket
(define (cpermit sl)
  (define-values [_ outl]
    (for/fold ([sl sl] [outl '()])
              ([i (length sl)])
      (values (append (rest sl) (list (first sl))) ; the new sl
              (cons sl outl)))) ; the new outl
  (reverse outl))

> (cpermit (list 1 2 3 4))
(list (list 1 2 3 4) (list 2 3 4 1) (list 3 4 1 2) (list 4 1 2 3))
```

And finally, the `(append (rest sl) (list (first sl)))` deserves to be its own helper function, because it has a clear purpose: to rotate the list once around.

```
#lang racket
;; rotate-once : (Listof A) -> (Listof A)
;; rotates a list once around, sending the first element to the back
(define (rotate-once lst)
  (append (rest lst) (list (first lst))))

(define (cpermit sl)
  (define-values [_ outl]
    (for/fold ([sl sl] [outl '()])
              ([i (length sl)])
      (values (rotate-once sl) ; the new sl
              (cons sl outl)))) ; the new outl
  (reverse outl))

> (cpermit (list 1 2 3 4))
(list (list 1 2 3 4) (list 2 3 4 1) (list 3 4 1 2) (list 4 1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code also works (without any helper function):

```
(define (cpermit sl)
  (define outl '())
  (for((i (length sl)))
    (set! sl (append (rest sl) (list (first sl))) )
    (set! outl (cons sl outl)))
  outl)

(cpermit '(1 2 3 4))
```

Output is:

```
'((1 2 3 4) (4 1 2 3) (3 4 1 2) (2 3 4 1))
```

Comment: That's fine *but*, "without any helper functions" should not be a goal. Helper functions are a good thing, especially if they have clear purposes

Comment: Also, you should avoid `set!`, since imperative code can disable optimizations. Instead, you could use a recursive helper function. If you want, you can define the helper function within the body of the `cpermit` function, I'll post an answer translating yours to that pattern

Answer (score 1):

Following solution is functional and short. I find that in many cases, helper functions can be replaced by default arguments:

```
(define (cpermit_1 sl (outl '()) (len (length sl)))
  (cond ((< len 1) outl)
        (else (define sl2 (append (rest sl) (list (first sl))))
              (cpermit_1 sl2 (cons sl2 outl) (sub1 len)))))
```

The output is:

```
(cpermit_1 '(1 2 3 4))
'((1 2 3 4) (4 1 2 3) (3 4 1 2) (2 3 4 1))
```